# Espresso tests failing after updating to Android API 28

Tags: android, android-espresso

In my tests, I launch an activity using the logic

```
val startIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).apply {
    setClassName(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().packageName, MyActivity::class.java.name)
    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
}

InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().startActivitySync(startIntent)
```

It was working fine when I was targeting API 27, but now that I'm targeting API 28 it fails with the exception

> android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

I know API 28 made a change to enforce using the above flag, but Im very clearly specifying that flag

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead:

```
addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
```